# Location current working directory in Colab

Tags: location, google-colaboratory

can anybody help me to find the current working directory in Colab. I am working on a project, which has a folder containing multiple sub-folders. When I need to read a text or csv file (in the same directory as nb) I have to locate my current notebook first which is quite tedious. I tried
`%pwd`
And also tried
 `import os`
`os.path`

The output for first one is simply
`/content`
While os.path does not output anything

Answer (score 0):

`/content` is where your notebook is, why you have to find it? Take example of a `test.txt` if it was in [files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTOOS.png). You can point to text file as `/content/test.txt`